# Searching for a probability distribution appropriate for my task

Tags: statistics, functions, probability-distributions, parametric

I'm making a game (not important), but I'd like to have real probability distribution function (instead of classical dice notation). I like the [normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), but I would like to also shift the odds so to speak to a given side. My crude drawing (not necessarily accurate):

[image]

I've tried to shift the function along x-axis, but that isn't it. Because sum must be always 100% (1.0) obviously. So the question is.

Is there some way to make normal distribution behave like this?
If not, is there some other parametric function (or distribution), that allows me to do it?

regards,
Kate

**Update**: Solution in Wolfram Mathematica (for anyone interested in this):

```
Manipulate[ListPlot[Table[{k, PDF[BetaBinomialDistribution[a, b, 50], k]}, {k, 0, 50}], Filling -> Axis], {a, 1, 3, 0.1}, {b, 3, 1, 0.1}]
```

Comment: Do you mean the density function is shifted, and perhaps scaled? Then the density is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\,\sigma}e^{(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)}$, where $\sigma\gt 0$ is at your disposal. (For the standard normal it is $1$.)

Comment: Does it need to be truncated, as in your drawing ? Meaning there is some kind of maximum for the value ? (note that this is not the case for normal distribution)

Comment: The picture is only crude. σ can vary, but this picture is shown for the same value of σ. The deviation is different, but somehow the rest of the curve must still be a probability distribution within a given range (1.0 or 2.0 in picture, but can be normalized really).

Comment: André Nicolas: I will try that. Edit: Wait.. that's a standard normal distribution function? But σ only shifts it, let me do a sanity check. Edit2: Yeah, that only shifts the bulge along the x-axis. But that's not what is in the picture. The picture might be deceiving. But sum must be also 1.0 for the curve

Comment: It was not clear to me whether the frame was for beauty or indicated a truncation. If we are confined to $[-2,2]$ what I mentioned is not appropriate.

Comment: To clarify, an example would be a weapon dealing damage (3 to 8 dmg for example), it would be distributed such, that 3 and 8 is least likely, and 5-6 most likely (crudely speaking). But now I want to give a skill to it. So beginner will have 3 most likely (even though the weapon is still 3-8). Immediate skilled player will have 5-6 (normal distribution), and expert will have 8 most likely. That's the idea behind it. Edit: except smooth transition between beginner, and expert of course

Comment: Wait a moment here:  do you only need a **discrete** distribution?  In other words, do you only need to generate integer values?  If so, then use a binomial distribution.  I can explain in more detail if that is the case.

Comment: In the end it will only integers, but I wasn't aware it makes difference. I need to somehow shift the weight as described in the previous example. So I can move the function maximum along the x-axis, but the distribution still give sum of 100%. In normal distribution it would be for example: 3 and 8 (5% of time), 4 and 7 (10%), 5 and 6 (35%). Now I want to change one parameter μ, and it will be shifted to left and it will give different distribution (made up estimation): 3 (50%), 4 (25%), 5 (12.5%).. etc. but still sum = 100%

Comment: You *definitely* will want to use a binomial distribution.  It would make everything super easy and simple.

Comment: OK, I'm checking it out. So many new (to me) distributions today. :D

Comment: I've tried it, here's a rewrite to Wolfram Alpha http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=BinomialDistribution%5B100%2C+0.2%5D but it only shifts a curve along the x-axis. But I'm unable to change the characteristics of the curve. Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am making a separate answer here because while my suggestion using a beta distribution remains applicable, the added information that the eventual distribution will be discrete makes another approach possible.

I suggest that a binomial distribution with appropriate parameters is suitable and easy to simulate.  Recall that if $X \sim {\rm Binomial}(n,p)$ is a binomially distributed random variable with parameters $n$ and $p$, where $n$ indicates the number of trials and $p$ is the probability of "success" for a single trial, then the probability mass function is $$\Pr[X = x] = \binom{n}{x} p^x (1-p)^{n-x}, \quad x = 0, 1, 2, \ldots, n.$$  The mean of the distribution is ${\rm E}[X] = np$, and the variance is ${\rm Var}[X] = np(1-p)$.  The selection of parameters is dictated by the desired support.  For instance, if the range of generated values is to be from $[1, 8]$, then we choose $n = 8-1 = 7$.  Then if the probability mass is to be concentrated on $Y = 6$, we want to choose $p$ such that $np = 6-1 = 5$, or $p = 5/7$.  Then we simulate $X \sim {\rm Binomial}(7,5/7)$ and calculate $Y = X + 1$.

To perform the actual simulation, we can simply generate $n$ independent and identically distributed Bernoulli trials, each of which has probability $p$ of "success," then count the number of successes.  In the above example, we would generate $7$ random reals $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_7$ on $[0,1]$, and count trial $i$ as a success if $x_i \le p$.

Now, the remaining issue is that of controlling variance.  The binomial model has two parameters but our parameter selection procedure does not allow us to choose the variance and therefore get finer control over the shape of the distribution.  To address this, we could go the cheap route and introduce a "pseudoparameter" $k$, which we multiply by $n$.  Then let $n^* = [kn]$ be the resulting rounded integer, and bin the simulated values appropriately.  This isn't really ideal, however.  A better solution would be to use the **beta-binomial** distribution.  But that is probably best left to another post.  For more information, see the wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution

Comment: Combination of discrete function, and beta distribution would be even more better, I guess. So far it seems, that I would only be distributing integer range of values, but it might be the case that later I would need beta distribution itself (the other answer basically). Most likely to combine more statistical incidents together.

Comment: The beta-binomial distribution is precisely the combination you mentioned.  It has the discreteness of the binomial, yet it has two shape parameters to allow better control of the mean and variance.

Comment: OK, thanks for two exhausting answers. Both of them correct, one better than the other. I will choose this one, because (as you mentioned) it fits more with the example I gave above in the comments.

Comment: Just FYI. I've already implemented it, and works perfectly as expected.

Answer (score 2):

From the picture that you've drawn, it seems that you want the distribution to have finite support--in other words, you want the range of the random values that you generate to be in some fixed interval.  In that case, shifting a normal distribution is not going to work, as you noted, because then you "chop off" a big chunk of probability mass if you shift the mean.

To correct this, you could renormalize the normal density, but to be honest, this is added computational complexity, and I think you would be better served by dealing directly with a more appropriate choice of parametric distribution.  Because your model seems to need finite support, a natural choice would be the beta distribution, whose probability density function is defined by $$f_X(x) = \frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)} x^{a-1} (1-x)^{b-1}, \quad 0 \le x \le 1,$$ where $a,b > 0$ are parameters that you set that determine the shape of the distribution.  To pick where the distribution has the "hump," you want to use the mode, which is $\frac{a-1}{a+b-2}$.  So for example, say you want the highest density to occur at $x = 2/3$.  Then you would solve the equation $$\frac{2}{3} = \frac{a-1}{a+b-2},$$ which would give you $a = 2b-1$.  That doesn't uniquely determine $a$ and $b$ yet.  The next decision you want to make is how narrow the peak at $2/3$ will be.  The general rule is that the larger the values of $a$ and $b$, the more narrow and tall the peak, and the greater the probability that the random number generated will be close to the corresponding $x$-value.  So if you want less variance, choose something like $b = 6$, $a = 11$.  If you want more variance, choose $b = 2$, $a = 3$.

If you want the peak of the distribution to be at $x = 1/2$, then obviously choose $a = b$.

Also, note that when $a = b = 1$, you get a uniform distribution, which is nice.

It should be pretty obvious that if you need your random number to be distributed on some other interval besides $[0,1]$, then you can simply apply an appropriate linear transformation $y = (d-c) x + c$ to get it in the interval $[c,d]$.

Finally, $a$ and $b$ are not required to be positive integers.  If they *are* positive integers, then the gamma functions in the front reduce to factorials, since for positive integer values of $z$, $\Gamma(z) = (z-1)!$; this can be computationally easier.  But $a$ and $b$ can be any real number, if you need them to be.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm looking at this beta distribution, and it looks promising, give me a minute.

Comment: I'm trying the beta distribution in a Wolfram Mathematica. If I put b=5 (for example - looks like normal distribution almost), and then go a=4,..3,..2,.. etc. it looks kind OK, but if I go the other way it behaves differently.

Comment: Did you try this?  Manipulate[Plot[PDF[BetaDistribution[a, b], x], {x, 0, 1}], {a, 1, 30, 1}, {b, 1, 30, 1}]

Comment: Oh I get it now. Also thanks for upgrading my Mathematica skills a notch. I now can notice that I need to go a={0,1,2,3,4} while b stays 5 (for example), and then to achieve the other (right) side I must do a=5, while b goes {4,3,2,1,0}. That seems to simulate exactly what I need.

Comment: And 3 seems to be the perfect value. Then left side is then a=[1, 3], b=3. Right side a=3, b=[3, 1]. Give me a while to confirm that.